# unexpected token import during npm start in react

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and created a mock up project but when I run the project I get the following error,my webpack.config.js file code is as follows,

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './client.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: 'public'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

my package.json file,

```js
{
  "name": "universal-react",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Universal React web application.",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack && node server.js",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:*",
    "watch:webpack": "webpack -w",
    "watch:server": "nodemon --ext js,jsx --ignore public/ server.js"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "keywords": [
    "universal",
    "react"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "marked": "^0.3.6",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

error message is as follows,

```js
/home/user/Documents/test/src/routes/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at loader (/home/user/Documents/src/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
```

Could anyone suggest me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not installed **babel-preset-es2015** as per your package.json.

```
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
```

try installing it via

```
npm install --save babel-preset-es2015
```

Also add

```
"babel": "^6.5.2",
"babel-cli": "^6.9.0"
```

and a `.babelrc` file in project root parallel to your `package.json`
with following content.

```
 $ cat .babelrc 
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

and then run npm install then webpack again.

Comment: did but still the same

Comment: what version of node.js are you using?

Comment: I use node v6.9.5

Comment: Getting the same issue. All presents in place. Any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: @pravin have installed all the presets as well?