# React call a component with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

## Hi all great programmers

## thanks for reading my question

## . My problem in react library is I want to call another component by one click.

## if you see code I have provided the necessary explanations with //*******

```
<pre>class CategoryList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        id: 0, name: "", title: "", description: "", subTitle: "", imagePath: "", tags: "",
        data: [],
        pageInfo: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
// read data is ok
}

renderCategories() {
// this function is ok
        return this.state.data.map(category => {
            return (
                <tr id={"one-row-" + category.id} key={category.id}>
                    <td>{category.id}</td>
                    <td>{category.name}</td>
                    <td>{category.title}</td>
                    <td>{category.description}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" href="#edit-modal" title="EDIT" onClick={(e) => this.editCategory(category)}>

                        EDIT</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    })
}

render() {
// this function is ok
        var ReturnView =
            <div>
                <h1 className="text-center">Categories</h1>
                <hr />
            <table className="table table-bordered table-striped table-hovered table-sortable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>title</th>
                        <th>desc</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {this.renderCategories()}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    return (
        ReturnView
    );
}


editCategory(category) {
    this.setState({
        id: category.id,
        name: category.name,
        title: category.title,
        description: category.description,
        subTitle: category.subTitle,
        imagePath: category.imagePath,
        tags: category.tags,
    }, function () {

// ***************** All My Problems is here *********************
 Category Edit  Component must call here 
        });
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <CategoryList subreddit="catgories" />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

the second component is here and i need call that and send parameters into that category edit component for rendering:

```
    class CategoryEdit extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id, name, title, description, subTitle, imagePath, tags
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
  //READ DATA FROM SERVER and work
    }

    render() {
        return (
           // CREATE UI and work
        )
    }

    editRow() {
        var id = this.state.id;
        var name = $("#edit-name").val();
        var title = $("#edit-title").val();
        var description = $("#edit-description").val();
        var subTitle = $("#edit-subTitle").val();
        var imagePath = $("#edit-imagePath").val();
        var tags = $("#edit-tags").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:49384/api/CategoryEdit",
            method: "POST",
            data: {"Id":id, "Name": name, "Title": title, "Description": description, "SubTitle": subTitle, "ImagePath": imagePath, "Tags": tags },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    alert(result.message);
                    if (result.isSuccess === true) {
                        this.setState({
                            id: id, name: name, title: title, description: description,
                            subTitle: subTitle, imagePath: imagePath, tags: tags
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <CategoryEdit />,
    document.getElementById('pop-up-content')
)
```

## What I have tried:

```
editCategory(category) {
        this.setState({
            id: category.id,
            name: category.name,
            title: category.title,
            description: category.description,
            subTitle: category.subTitle,
            imagePath: category.imagePath,
            tags: category.tags,
        }, function () {
            <CategoryEdit props="this.state" />
        });
    }

editCategory(category) {
     this.setState({
         id: category.id,
         name: category.name,
         title: category.title,
         description: category.description,
         subTitle: category.subTitle,
         imagePath: category.imagePath,
         tags: category.tags,
     }, function () {
         ReactDOM.render(
             <CategoryEdit props="this.state" />,
             document.getElementById('pop-up-content')
         );
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to render new `editPage` component when clicked on any specific category from the table from edit that category. Am I right? If it is your issue then I will provide you a solution.

```
npm i react-router -s
npm i react-router-dom -s
```

install these two libraries.

so this is your list component.
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

```
export class CategoryList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        pageInfo: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
// read data is ok
}

renderCategories() {
// this function is ok
        return this.state.data.map(category => {
            return (
                <tr id={"one-row-" + category.id} key={category.id}>
                    <td>{category.id}</td>
                    <td>{category.name}</td>
                    <td>{category.title}</td>
                    <td>{category.description}</td>
                    <td>
                        <Link
                           className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                           to={`/edit/${category.id}`}
                         > 
                           Edit Category
                        </Link>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    })
}
```

and this is your edit component:

```
    class CategoryEdit extends React. Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                id, name, title, description, subTitle, imagePath, tags
            };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            const id = this.props.match.params.id;
            /*Call server to get details of that catagory using this id. Get response and set the response in your state like:-
       this.setState({title: response.title, description: response.description}) etc. */
        }

        updateCatagory = () => {
          //this is your method to update category with new values in server.
         const {id, name, title, etc..... all params} = this.state;

           $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:49384/api/CategoryEdit",
            method: "POST",
            data: {"Id":id, "Name": name, "Title": title, "Description": description, "SubTitle": subTitle, "ImagePath": imagePath, "Tags": tags },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                    this.history.push('/');
              }
          });
        }

        render() {
            return (
               // CREATE UI and work
               //Add a button here.
               <button onClick={this.updateCatagory}>Update Catagory</button>
            )
        }
```

create a new component `index.jsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Route, BrowserRouter, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {CategoryList} from './your-path-to-component';
import {CategoryEdit} from './your-path-to-component';

    ReactDOM.render(
            <HashRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact={true} path="/" component={CategoryList}/>
                    <Route exact={true} path="/edit/:id" component={CategoryEdit}/>
                </Switch>
            </HashRouter>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
}
```

Comment: i tried  import and export but them does not work in my code .

Comment: Do you have idea about react router. Than you can easily handle this.

Comment: Please learn about `react-router`. I will provide code for implementation.
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: I have modified your component in my answer please have a look and if you have doubt about file structure then you can check this repo. https://github.com/gajesh1/MyWork/. You can check `src/`.

Comment: for writing import and export i need use es6   is that  write?

now i have error : Unexpected identifier for import ! .

Comment: Yes, You can change your webpack config to for es6 support or if you want to use es5 then use `require` instead of `import`. Check this link for es6 support
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574933/unexpected-token-import-during-npm-start-in-react?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Hi  GAJESH PANIGRAHI 
thanks for reading my question,

In a react app i using this scripts with this periority :
jquery-3.3.1.js
es6.js
react.js
react-dom.js
react-with-addons.js
react-router.js
react-router-dom.js
browser.js
bootstrap.js

when i create class like this :
class className
===============
have No Error  and react working good
but when i create my class like this :
export class className
======================
browser occured me an error message :  "exports is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the component to be rendered inside the render method, In order to render it on Click, you can setState a active state and render it conditionally like

```
editCategory(category) {
        this.setState({
            id: category.id,
            name: category.name,
            title: category.title,
            description: category.description,
            subTitle: category.subTitle,
            imagePath: category.imagePath,
            tags: category.tags,
            isActive : true
        });
    }

    render() {
       const { isActive, ...rest } = this.state;
       return (
          <div>
             <div>{ReturnView}</div>
             {isActive && <CategoryEdit {...rest}/>}
         </div>
       );
    }
```

Comment: Shubham Khatri  thanks for read and answer. but I think I did not correctly say my purpose.

i need call reactdom.render in editCategory
because this method want call other js file that is a component 

render method is not my target .

Comment: Shubham Khatri  thanks for read and answer. but I think I did not correctly say my purpose.

Comment: Given this example.

function CLICK() {
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

As you can see in this example, the element is built inside the function and is not a component, but in my project element alone is a separate component and dose not work .  :(